# Error: unknown command "/bin/sh" for "deck"

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I am trying to run deck commands inside docker container in jenkins pipeline but I am seeing permission issues when deck try to access file in gitrepo.So,I tried to mount the file in gitrepo to docker container so that permission issues should be eliminated.But when I try to mount I am seeing following error can someone help me on this
Command to mount file to docker container in jenkins pipeline as follows
sh "docker run -v $PWD/kong.yaml:/root/app/kong.yaml api-deck:latest"

Docker file as follows

FROM hbagdi/deck
WORKDIR /kong-configs

COPY . .
RUN deck version
CMD echo "Hello world"

ENTRYPOINT ["deck"]

Comment: did you find solution?